# Allowing plugin/API access to instantiate "protected" classes

Tags: java, c#

This question is technically for a C# project, but it's generic enough it could easily apply to Java as well.

I'm in the early stages of developing a "plugin" API for a commercial application. I produce a DLL (or jar) of interfaces users can use to build a plugin for the application.

As a commercial application, I don't want to expose much of the implementation or source code.

My problem is that I can't decide how to handle situations where a plugin may need to *instantiate* a class that belongs to the application. They clearly need access to it, but I don't want to publish the source (other than details you'd get with an interface, of course).

As an example, I want to let a plugin create a new `Recipe`:

`new Recipe(new Bread(), new Flour(2), new Yeast(), ...)`

This means I can't just give them a `Recipe` and ingredients interfaces or abstract classes. So, I have two choices:

- Provide the Recipe, and all ingredients classes in the API. Not what I want.
- Create a factory method. The user can call the factory, which internally creates and returns the new `Recipe`

Are there any other methods I'm missing?

`Recipe` is easy to make a factory for because it's a single class, but I don't see a clean way of making a factory to get the "ingredients".

All I can think of is registering them with a string ID, ENUM, or even an interface for every single item, allowing the user to reference them without having the actual class.

The interface method will double the files needed for ingredients, but in the end it's cleanest for the user.

I picture a factory method like:

`var flour = CreateIngredient<IFlour>();`

Comment: This question is a bit abstract. Why is it that you can't give the plugin access to certain objects? What I would suggest is perhaps is instead of having the plugin manipulate whatever objects directly, it builds a description of what the host should do. For example instead of having access to a Recipe it has a RecipeBuilder, that might have methods like to add ingredients. Something like `CreateRecipe(r => r.AddBread().AddFlour(2).AddYeast())` and so on.

Comment: Because in the long run this is going to a very robust API, allowing them access to all sorts of areas of the application. The more we open up for modification the more I'd wind up publishing and that's just not feasible with a commercial project. I've considered a builder as well, as we get more complex objects I will likely use one. I can't have hard-coded methods though because that breaks support for plugged-in changes. If someone replaces Yeast with a plugin-created ingredient CandyCane, the builder has to support it.